# Let $S=\{1,5,9\}$. Prove that if $n\in S$ and $\frac{n^2+n-6}{2}$ is odd, then $\frac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{6}$ is even.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $S=\{1,5,9\}$. Prove that if $n\in S$ and $\frac{n^2+n-6}{2}$ is odd, then $\frac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{6}$ is even.

I first assumed $\frac{n^2+n-6}{2}$ is odd. Since $n\in S$, n must be either $\{1,5,9\}$ so I attempted to plug in all values into the fraction and I get even integers only.

Comment: This is an example of [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth); the material implication $P\implies Q$ is defined to be false only when $P$ is true but $Q$ is false, otherwise it is true, which means that if $P$ is false, $P\implies Q$ is true regardless of the truth value of $Q$.$$\\$$
Funnily enough, there's a joke exercise on vacuous truth in H.L. Royden's real analysis book which went like: "Prove that, if $x\in\emptyset$, then $x$ is a green-eyed lion."

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{2n^3+3n^2+n}6=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$$ will be even iff $$\dfrac{n(n+1)}2\ \ \ \ (1)\text{ is even as (3,2)=1  and } 2n+1\text{ is odd}$$

Again $\dfrac{n^2+n-6}2=\dfrac{n(n+1)}2-3\ \ \ \ (2)$

Clearly $(1),(2)$ have opposite parities.

Observe that $n+1,n$ also have opposite parities.

So, exactly one of $\{n,n+1, 2n+1\}$ will be even

So, we need $n\equiv 0,-1\equiv3\pmod4$

Answer (score 0):

A logical implication "if $A$ then $B$" is formally correct when $A$ is false. In our case, $A$ is "$n\in S$ and $\frac{n^2+n-6}{2}$ is odd" and $B$ is "$\frac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{6}$ is even".